# How to send javascript key-value pair to server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, key-value

I have a key value pair which i want to send to server.
e.g: 
var obj = {'item1': true, 'item2': false, ........};

I want to send this information to server by ajax call.
But at server side i am unable to get individual value. At server side i am getting "object" as string.
I am using jQuery for making an ajax call.

Can anyone please give any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got answer to my question. This can be done by using:

```
var obj = {'item1': true, 'item2': false, ........};
$.post("test.php", {data: JSON.stringify(obj)});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = $.JSON.encode(obj);
$.post("test.php", {data:a});
```

Use a [JSON decoder](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the string in `$_POST["data"]` to an associate array at the server side.

```
<?php
  $json = $_POST["data"]
  var_dump(json_decode($json));
?>
```